Trouble with hair density at scalp
I made a 3D model and I am now trying to set hair particles on the head for simulation. However, just as I generate the hair, it appears very patchy. Most of the children are going through the head leading to the scalp appearing less dense and almost creating a balding effect. How can I remedy this? 

It may not be as patchy as it looks, as solid viewport usually draws hair as thin as possible. But anyways, does the scalp have collision physics set?
